# To check a condition in a column and then perform operation in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table that goes like below:

```
PO_No     Line_item     Quantity      Value       PO_quantity           PO_value
101         10            100           5000           70                 5000 
101         10            -30          -2000           70                 5000 
101         20            200           7000           50                 1000
101         20            -50          -3500           50                 1000 
101         30            80            2000           100                3000
101         30            40            1250           100                3000
```

Now I want to first concatenate PO_No and Line_item (which is easy) and then check for each combination of **concat(PO_No,Line_item)**, whether there is a negative value in the **Quantity** column. If yes, then sum up the Quantity values and compare with PO_quantity. In the end, the result should be like:

```
PO_No  Line_item  quantity  Value  PO_quantity  PO_value Comments
___________________________________________________________________________
101  10  70  3000  70  5000   Quantity & PO_quantity match and negative value in Quantity present
101  20  150 3500  50  1000   Quantity & PO_quantity unmatched and negative value in Quantity present
101  30  120 3250  100 3000   Quantity & PO_quantity unmatched and negative value in Quantity not present
```

Can you please help in how to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: And what if there is no negative value? Which row PO quantity do you compare? How PO value calculated in the result

Comment: If negative value is not present, the sum of the quantities shud not take place. PO quantity is same for each combination for PO and Line_item. Hence, for above example, for 101-10,PO qty is 70.. for 101-20, PO qty is 50.

Comment: It wold be better if you extend you example with not negative rows for the same po-line. Because now it seems quantity is already calculated in column PO_quantity

Comment: added!! Actually the requirement is that after taking the sum, the result comment should mention whether the Quantity column had a negative value or no(as edited in the desired output above). Thanks!!

Comment: sorry.. it should be 3250. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation with case:

```
select PO_No, Line_item, quantity, Value, PO_quantity, PO_value, 
       concat(
          case when quantity=po_quantity then 'Quantity & PO_quantity match and negative value in Quantity ' 
               else 'Quantity & PO_quantity unmatched and negative value in Quantity ' end,
          case when  min_quantity<0 then 'present' else 'not present'  end
          ) as comments                                                                
  from
      (
       select  PO_No,           Line_item ,
               sum(quantity)    quantity,
               min(quantity)    min_quantity,
               sum(value)       value,
               min(po_quantity) po_quantity,
               min(PO_value)    PO_value
       from
            (--Use your table instead of this subquery
             select stack(6, --PO_No     Line_item     Quantity      Value       PO_quantity           PO_value
                               101,         10,          100,        5000,          70 ,               5000,
                               101,         10,          -30,       -2000,          70 ,               5000,
                               101,         20,          200,        7000,          50 ,               1000,
                               101,         20,          -50,       -3500,          50 ,               1000,
                               101,         30,          80 ,        2000,          100,               3000,
                               101,         30,          40 ,        1250,          100,               3000
                          ) as (PO_No,Line_item,Quantity,Value,PO_quantity,PO_value)
            ) your_table
       group by PO_No, Line_item 
       )s
order by     PO_No, Line_item
```

Result:

```
OK
101     10      70      3000    70      5000    Quantity & PO_quantity match and negative value in Quantity present
101     20      150     3500    50      1000    Quantity & PO_quantity unmatched and negative value in Quantity present
101     30      120     3250    100     3000    Quantity & PO_quantity unmatched and negative value in Quantity not present
Time taken: 136.559 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Just replace 'your_table' subquery with your table.

Comment: thanks a lot...!! it worked absolutely as per the requirement. Never knew that cases comments too can be concatenated. Thank you again!!!